# What are the architectural differences between Angular 2 vs Angular 4 vs Angular 5?

Tags: angular, architecture

I was majorly working on Angular 1 and recently I started working on Angular 2 and I understand the architecture changes of Angular 2. Angular 2 is quite different from its predecessor. It is component based, use of controllers and scope has been depreciated. Syntax and structure have also changed and many more changes. I have also been hearing about Angular 4 and recently started hearing about Angular 5, but I could not find any online resource from where I could understand and compare the different architectural changes in these major versions. Can you help me in understanding the architectural difference between Angular 2 vs Angular 4 vs Angular 5?

Answer (score 0):

If you really look at the changelog, **`angular2/4/5`**  are all mean the same. Well there is no path breaking change that means Angular 4 is not a complete rewrite of Angular 2 . Same goes with angular 5 as well.

There is no major architectural changes, but there have been fixes and some new features which you can go through **[`changelog`](https://angular.io/guide/change-log)**